# What can be the cause of "Etat HTTP 500" error? how can resolve it?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem in dynamic web application runned via eclipse, every time I try to test it, this error message is outputed (knowing that some links work but after short time are crashed):

```
Etat HTTP 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Rapport d'exception

message 

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne () qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException
    org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)


cause mère 

javax.servlet.ServletException
    org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:696)
    org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:456)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)


cause mère 

org.n52.oxf.OXFException
    org.n52.oxf.feature.sos.SOSObservationStore.unmarshalFeatures100(SOSObservationStore.java:114)
    org.n52.oxf.feature.sos.SOSObservationStore.unmarshalFeatures(SOSObservationStore.java:63)
    org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:669)
    org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:456)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)


note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de Apache Tomcat/5.5.12.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/5.5.12
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 generally means that your program on the server side crashed or otherwise errored out.

In your case, a servlet had an error at

```
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:696)
```

and the exception was

```
org.n52.oxf.OXFException
```

Comment: Thnx skaffman for Your replay, but I didn'nt understand what's exactly the problem? how resolve this type of error?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer that.  We would need to see the code for the servlet RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType or whatever code you wrote to call that.  What you've provided tells us only that your servlet died, and gives a clue as to where in the code.

Comment: This is the code of the RestSosFrontend servlet (just the function of showResultsInPreferredMIMEType because the code is s long)

Comment: private void showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(ParameterContainer paramCon, OperationResult opResult, String serviceVersion, HttpServletResponse response, String headerValue, String requestURL) throws IOException, ServletException {
  OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
  try {

   String preferredMIMEype = getPreferredMIMEtype(headerValue);

   // if(preferredMIMEype.equals("image/jpeg")){ //to test
   if (preferredMIMEype.equals("text/xml")) {

    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    out.write(opResult.getIncomingResult());
   }

Comment: else if (preferredMIMEype.equals("image/jpeg")) {

    IFeatureStore featureStore = new SOSObservationStore();
    IChartRenderer renderer = new TimeSeriesChartRenderer4xPhenomenons();
    OXFFeatureCollection featureColl = featureStore.unmarshalFeatures(opResult);
    BufferedImage chartImage = (BufferedImage) renderer.renderChart(featureColl, paramCon, 500, 500).getRendering(); 
    // write image to output stream:

Comment: response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(chartImage);
    param.setQuality(1, false);
    encoder.encode(chartImage, param);
    // }else if(preferredMIMEype.equals("image/jpeg")){ //to test
   }

Comment: else if (preferredMIMEype.equals("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml")) {

    String diagramRequestURL = requestURL.replace("KML", "DIAGRAM"); 
String xslFile = "om2kml.xsl";
    if (serviceVersion.equals("0.0.0")) {
     xslFile = "om2kml_00.xsl";
    }

Comment: InputStream xslInput = RestSosFrontend.class.getResourceAsStream(xslFile);
    String xslScript = IOHelper.readText(xslInput);
    xslScript = xslScript.replace("@DIAGRAM_URL@", diagramRequestURL + "/diagram.jpg");

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
    XSLTTransformer.transform(new String(opResult.getIncomingResult()), xslScript, out);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new ServletException(e);
  }
 }